# Connecting to multiple client's local SQL servers from Cloud based IIS

Tags: iis, web-deployment, cloud-hosting

I am developing a web app that is not doing anything fancy.  The parent company wants to use a `cloud based IIS` service to support the web app and then submit the information to the client's `local SQL servers` through the internet and the client's firewalls.

Traffic isn't that much of an issue, we are talking about probably no more than `10` submissions daily per client.  My question is with regard to connecting to the client's SQL servers and running the `Stored Proc` on each server.

*We already have admin privileges on the firewalls and servers to do what we need to do to make anything happen*.

**What would be my best/reliable/secure method to implement this service?**

Page asks for 10 items of info then submits to Stored Proc, that's it... with a local IIS server there is no problem, works nice.  I want to make sure that the information stays secured, not just for the 10 items, but the SQL server and any security between it and the IIS server.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting up a VPN tunnel between the remote IIS server and the in-house SQL server.  With a VPN tunnel, the SQL server is just like any other server on the network to the app.